# In zoom chat, how do you pop the chat back in after it popped out?

Tags: zoom-meeting

In zoom chat, how do you pop the chat back in after it popped out?

[image]

Comment: @John no that doesn't answer it.  All you are talking about is how to bring up the chat and to close the chat, not to pop it back in. i.e. to "dock" it

Comment: Thank you. I did not interpret the question as docking and undocking chat. Chat is controlled by the host and there is a setting to dock and undock:   https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/203650445-In-meeting-chat

Comment: @John I was/am not the host and I undocked the chat(there was an option to 'pop out' the chat), that I clicked, and I cannot see how to dock(pop the chat back to where it was), the chat.

Comment: I went into Zoom but I do not have an active meeting. There may be 3 dots (...) (Options) in the undocked Chat Window (I cannot determine without a meeting).  Try looking there.

Comment: @John i'm not in an active meeting either so I can't see anymore than you can.

Comment: @John  here https://zoom.us/test in this way we can see the options available in an active meeting by going to that test meeting. I can't see an option that docks it after it has been undocked, maybe you can see and screenshot it?

Comment: I cannot replicate everything (lack of active meeting). Try picking up the Chat Window (mouse) and moving it wholly within the main Zoom Window.  Once fully inside, it may dock properly. The main chat options are (at least can be) controlled by the host.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110568/discussion-between-barlop-and-john).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pop a Chat Window back in (tested in Zoom Meeting test). In the Chat Window (undocked), click on the Option dots lower right and Select Merge to main Window.

[image]

Comment: this doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Rainb yes it does. I tested it.  If you think it doesn't then make a brief video and post it. .you could make the video and post it on youtube or use screencast to make the video. and link to it.. Or, ask your own question. And you could at least be more descriptive than claiming it doesn't work. e.g. do you see the option he highightd.. what have you clicked, what do you see. e.t.c. you can post images links from imgur

Comment: This is a Zoom feature I use frequently and it continues to work properly nearly a year after this thread. As @barlop notes, you can ask another question.

Answer (score 5):

To put the complete answer in a single post...

The solution is simple but not intuitive. I think that if anyone has to ask the question, the user interface design needs improvement. With Zoom, that is definitely the case.
It's very easy and yet it took me a long time to discover.

1. Open a Zoom meeting. You can create a meeting yourself or simply wait until next time you are in a meeting you were invited to. It makes no difference. You can make the necessary change at any time.
2. Make sure Zoom is NOT in full screen mode. In the top right corner of the main Zoom window just to the left of the standard Windows “X” (close or exit app) you should see a small, single square box. If you see what looks like two small boxes stacked on top of one another you are not in full screen mode.
3. The popped-out chat window has an ellipses (...) on the right edge. Click on it to display a handful of options. Select "Merge To Meeting Window" and SHAZZAM, your chat window is returned to it's original home.
   [image of return zoom chat window to main zoom display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeANV.png)

Comment: Forwarded from @ezfzx: "The pop-out option is called "Pop Out", but the un-pop-out option is called "Merge to Meeting Window", which could be interpreted a lot of different ways.".

Comment: Is it always a pop-out in full screen mode?

Answer (score 1):

Docking the chat window does not work when using Zoom with your display in full screen mode.

It only works in regular window mode.

You will only see the option to dock the chat (3 dots at bottom right of chat window) when viewing your display in regular window mode.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered pop out by accident. Took me several days to stumble again. I want to see list of participants during meeting with videos off so I can toggle between mute and unmute when someone speaks while presenting a powerpoint.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).